# HTML Canvas Refresh Some Part, Not All

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I want to create some kind of meme generator using HTML Canvas, which has 2 text inserted from 2 text fields. here's my code :

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color: #ffb515;">
        Sorry, canvas not supported
    </canvas>

    <img id="canvasimg" src="kindle.jpg" style="display:none;"/>

    <input type='text' value='enter some text' id='canvastext-top'/>
    <input type='text' value='enter some text' id='canvastext-bottom'/>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;;
        canvasWidth = Math.min(500, deviceWidth-20);
        canvasHeight = Math.min(500, deviceWidth-20);

        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
        canvas.height = canvasHeight;

        var img = document.getElementById('canvasimg');

        img.onload = function() {
            x = canvas.width/2 - img.width/2;
            y = canvas.height/2 - img.height/2;
            //ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
        }

        $("#canvastext-top").keyup(function(){              
            ctx.lineWidth = 8;
            ctx.font = '20pt Verdana';
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

            var text = document.getElementById('canvastext-top').value;
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            x = canvas.width/2;
            y = canvas.height - canvas.height/1.2;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
            ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
        });


        $("#canvastext-bottom").keyup(function(){               
            ctx.lineWidth = 8;
            ctx.font = '20pt Verdana';
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

            var text = document.getElementById('canvastext-bottom').value;
            text = text.toUpperCase();
            x = canvas.width/2;
            y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
            ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

now the problem is in this line :

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

If I'm not refreshing my canvas, the text will look like this :

[image: ugly text without no refresh]

but, if I'm using that refresh canvas method, once I type on the second text field, the first text will be refreshed and disappear.

how to still use this refresh but keep the first text on the canvas while editting the second text. and vice versa.

thank you.

PS : here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/robtn532/

Comment: You should write a render loop where you: clear the canvas then draw both the variables to screen. You won't be able to partially render the canvas and using the key events means you cant do all the opertaions you need to do at once. If you add a fiddle or plunker we can help more.

Comment: @AndyLewis : updated. there's fiddle now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/af5jf0ob/

So essentially I moved all of your drawing logic into one function that is called repeatedly. Every time the function is called it reads the value from the textboxes and renders them to the screen in one pass. This is the same as a basic game loop. The code can be tidied up a bit yet but this should get you going.

```
var text1Y = y = canvas.height - canvas.height/1.2;
var text2Y = y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
function runLoop(){
    ctx.lineWidth  = 8;
    ctx.font = '20pt Verdana';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

    var text1 = document.getElementById('canvastext-top').value;
    text1 = text1.toUpperCase();


    var text2 = document.getElementById('canvastext-bottom').value;
    text2 = text2.toUpperCase();

    x = canvas.width/2;
    y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeText(text1, x, text1Y);
    ctx.fillText(text1, x, text1Y);

    ctx.strokeText(text2, x, text2Y);
    ctx.fillText(text2, x, text2Y);
     window.setTimeout(runLoop, 14);
};
runLoop();
```

Comment: bro, your code works, but why my image doesn't show up?

Comment: You need to add a line to draw it inside the runLoop function: ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); This loop draws everthing in one go so simply add more lines to draw more things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need 1 function that draws everything which is being called on keyup.

```
var drawText = function() {
   ctx.lineWidth = 8;
   ctx.font = '20pt Verdana';
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
   ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   ctx.textAlign = 'center';
   ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   var text = document.getElementById('canvastext-top').value;
   text = text.toUpperCase();
   x = canvas.width/2;
   y = canvas.height - canvas.height/1.2;            
   ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
   ctx.fillText(text, x, y);

   var text = document.getElementById('canvastext-bottom').value;
   text = text.toUpperCase();
   x = canvas.width/2;
   y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
   ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
   ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

$("#canvastext-top").keyup(function(){              
   drawText();            
});


$("#canvastext-bottom").keyup(function(){               
   drawText();            
});
```

Comment: because it's just a part of your code you should change like this http://jsfiddle.net/robtn532/1/

Comment: bro, your code now works. but I'm facing another problem here. as you can see before, I have this line of code : //ctx.drawImage(img, x, y); basically it will show the image under the text. but, your code refresh everything and make the image disappear as well. how to keep the image and placed under the text?

Comment: as I said you need one function that draws generally everything (text, images, whatever) when you need it.